# Finding maximum length difference between strings of two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop

So I've tried to used a nested loop and add the lengths to a int array and then go through the int array and find the highest number but it doesn't pass the test case and I'm starting to think that maybe I'm overcomplicating this problem and that there's a much simpler approach. Here is what I've tried.

```
public static int mxdiflg(String[] a1, String[] a2) {
    int maxDiff=0;
    int[] lengths=new int[a1.length*a2.length];
    for(int i=0;i<a1.length;i++){
      for(int j=0;j<a2.length;j++){
        lengths[j]=Math.abs(a1[j].length()-a2[i].length());
      }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<lengths.length;i++){
      if(lengths[i]>maxDiff){
        maxDiff=lengths[i];
      }
        
    }
  
  return maxDiff;
  
}
```

Comment: Could you find the length of the longest string "N" and the length of the shortest string "n" and take N-n as the result?

Comment: Omg I didn't even think of that! I feel like such an idiot but I think I should be able to solve it if I try this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your indexing for `lengths` array go to only to max value of `j` when it should go to `i * j`, and you have swapped the outer-loop var `i` with the inner-loop var `j`. Change the line in the nested loop to `lengths[i*j+j]=Math.abs(a1[i].length()-a2[j].length());`

Comment: Your Question is not entirely clear. Could use some editing for clarity.

Comment: It might help if you added some test cases to show what you're trying to achieve as I notice mine and the other answer interprète the problem differently. In particular if both the shortest and longest words are in the same array what should happen?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like so with two independent loops.

```
String[] a1 = { "ab", "cdefghik", "lsls" };
String[] a2 = { "a", "cdefghik", "lsls", "abcdefghijkl" };

int max = mxdiflg(a1, a2);
System.out.println(max);
```

prints

```
11
```

- initialize the `minvals` to `largest int` value and the `maxvals` to `0`.
- each loop finds the `min` and `max` of the strings using `Math.min` and `Math.max`.
- once done, find the `maximum` of the `two max values` and the `minimum` of the `two min values.`
- the subtract the `minimum` from the `maximum` and you have the result.

```
public static int mxdiflg(String[] a1, String[] a2) {
    int maxa1 = 0, mina1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE, maxa2 = 0,
            mina2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    
    // find max and
    for (String s : a1) {
        int len = s.length();
        maxa1 = Math.max(maxa1, len);
        mina1 = Math.min(mina1, len);
    }
    for (String s : a2) {
        int len = s.length();
        maxa2 = Math.max(maxa2, len);
        mina2 = Math.min(mina2, len);
    }
    
    return Math.max(maxa1, maxa2) - Math.min(mina1, mina2);
}
```

Note:  Due to the peculiarities of various character encodings, `String.length` does accurately count the characters. As stated in the documentation.

> Returns the length of this string. The length is equal to the number of [Unicode code units](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) in the string.

As some characters use encoding schemes of more than 8 bits, their reported length would greater than `1`.

If this is important, the `s.length` could be replaced with `(int)s.codePoints().count()` to handle these encodings.

Comment: Fails when comparing `{ "ab" }` to `{ "a" }`. Result is 1 rather than 0, as [seen on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/y8kkmd). I suggest replacing `s.length()` with `s.codePoints().count()`. That `count` method returns `long`, so we must convert to `int` to fit your other code. So `int len = s.length();` becomes `int len = Math.toIntExact( s.codePoints().count() ) ;` as [seen on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/y8kkmd).

Comment: Thanks! Per your comment I was looking for something like codePoints.count().  Good to know.  But codePoints and character encodings could be considered as advanced as streams.

Comment: This gives a different answer to my suggested answer when both the shortest and longest words are in the same array. I'm not sure which is correct and have asked for clarification in the comments above, but one of us is wrong.

Comment: @WJS No, I disagree about code points being advanced. Teaching code points should be taught as part of Java 101. Teaching the broken `char` type is a huge disservice to students. I find it strange how so many Java programmers cling to `char`, similar to how many defended the terrible date-time classes even in the face of Joda-Time & java.time. … If you don't want to incorporate the code points into your otherwise good Answer, I can write my own Answer.

Comment: @SteveBosman you raise a good point.  Otherwise, the two arrays could be streamed as one to find the `min and max` using `summaryStatistics`.

Comment: @BasilBourque  Perhaps.  But the keepers ofJava should provide a reasonable alternative to the `String.length` method to get what any normal person would expect with `length`. One should not have to stream and count codepoints to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Java 8+ and a reasonable number of strings in each array, I'd suggest using the following to avoid the nested loop:

```
int a1max = Arrays.stream(a1).mapToInt(String::length).max().orElse(0);
int a1min = Arrays.stream(a1).mapToInt(String::length).min().orElse(0);
int a2max = Arrays.stream(a2).mapToInt(String::length).max().orElse(0);
int a2min = Arrays.stream(a2).mapToInt(String::length).min().orElse(0);

int maxDiff = Math.max(Math.abs(a2max-a1min), Math.abs(a1max-a2min));
```

Comment: What is Arrays.stream and mapToInt? I'm still a bit new to programming and I don't really know what this syntax does exactly or what it means.

Comment: @Eduardom2002 Streams are part of the new [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) features added in recent years to Java’s already existing [object-oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) features. Streams and lambdas are advanced concepts that should likely be deferred when first learning Java, though ironically they are easy to use once you grasp the concepts.